# Triangulate points with edges

Tags: points, triangulation, edges

I have a set of points + edges connecting pairs of them. There are enough edges so that one can triangulate the points by choosing a subset of the edges; That is exactly what I want to do - find a triangulation that uses the existing edges and does not add new edges that didn't exist in the original graph.
Is there existing code for doing that?

Comment: How can you tell there are enough edges so that a triangulation exists as a subset?

Comment: @SamuelTan - For brevity, I just said "There are enough edges so that one can triangulate the points by choosing a subset of the edges" - the reason that is true is beyond the scope of my question, but in my case I can assure you it is true :)

Comment: If there was a way to check whether this was true in your program, I was thinking, can't you go through all the edges removing them one by one and checking the triangulability condition, and dropping those edges which when removed still permit triangulation. For this approach to give you all possible solutions you would have to permute the order in which the edges are removed. If you can't find code for this perhaps you could write it yourself based on this idea. The key is the triangulability condition. Maybe you could search for that as well.